# Error while testing Yolo model on an image

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolo

I've been using code from this link https://github.com/msindev/YOLO-v3-Object-Detection/blob/master/yolo_detection_images.py.
And there's a few changes that I did to the code such as the path to my cfg, weight, and coco files and the other change is `[layerName[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]` to `[layerName[i - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]`. And I got the following error:

```
 IndexError `index 57 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1` at `color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]`.
```

Is there any way I can fix this? I'm trying to run yolo model on a local machine.
Edit: change the index error from image to text.

Comment: Hi @Nandatto, welcome to SO!   [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)   The **IndexError** in your case is suggesting that your code is trying to access an index (57) from an array that contains a single value (as indicated by the error log)

Comment: Sorry, done edit the post. How can I fix this? I don't understand.

Comment: It is simple, please see the [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). To correct the error, you need to verify what lengths are the following two arrays in runtime: **COLORS**, **classIDs**.You can use `print(len(classIDs))` and `print(len(COLORS))` to see the lengths.

Comment: Thank you vyi, I print both COLORS and classIDs, and then I match both the value in my code and it works.!